# How can I save an array inside of an array using React Context? "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Keywords')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, fetch-api, react-context

I'm making a fetch request that sends back a JSON with an Array of Documents and inside the array of Documents I get another array of "Keywords". I am able to save the Documents array with React Context but I get an error when trying to save the Keywords array. The error I get is the following: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Keywords')".

This is an example of the response I get so you can see the structure of the JSON:
[image: WorkView Context - Image from Google Chrome React Dev Tools Extension]

Here is my code:

Dashboard.jsx -> Here is where I make the fetch request.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useWorkViewContext } from "../hooks/useWorkViewContext";

function Dashboard({ user }) {
  const { workview, keywords, dispatch } = useWorkViewContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkView = async () => {
      const credentials =
        import.meta.env.VITE_SERVICE_USER +
        ":" +
        import.meta.env.VITE_SERVICE_PASSWORD;
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://urlforfetch.com",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            WorkViewApplication: "VAPR",
            WorkViewClassName: "Policy",
            WorkViewFilter: "All Policy Record",
            SearchAttributes: [
              {
                Name: "InsuranceCarrier",
                Value: "MAPFRE",
              },
            ],
          }),
        }
      );
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        localStorage.setItem("workview", JSON.stringify(json.Documents));
        localStorage.setItem(
          "keywords",
          JSON.stringify(json.Documents[0].Keywords)
        );
        dispatch(
          { type: "SET_WORKVIEW", payload: json.Documents },
          {
            type: "SET_KEYWORDS",
            payload: JSON.stringify(json.Documents[0].Keywords),
          }
        );
      }
    };

    if (user) {
      fetchWorkView();
    }
  }, [dispatch, user]);

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="dashboard">
        <h1>
          Welcome back, <span className="accent">{user.username}</span>
        </h1>
        <div className="grid-sm">
          <div className="grid-sm">
            <p>In this section you will find you cases information.</p>
          </div>
          <div className="grid-lg">
            <h2>My Cases</h2>
            {workview && workview.length > 0 && (
              <div className="grid-md">
                {workview.map((document, index) => (
                  <>
                    <a key={index} href={document.DocumentURL}>
                      {document.DocumentName}
                    </a>
                  </>
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
            {keywords && keywords.length > 0 && (
              <div className="grid-md">
                {keywords.map((keyword, index) => (
                  <>
                    <a key={index}>{keyword.Name}</a>
                  </>
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

WorkViewContext.jsx

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const WorkViewContext = createContext();

export const workviewReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_WORKVIEW":
      return {
        workview: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_KEYWORDS":
      return {
        keywords: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const WorkViewContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workviewReducer, {
    workview: null,
    keywords: null,
  });

  return (
    <WorkViewContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </WorkViewContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Using the save to local storage function I was able to save the Documents[0].Keywords array but I can't save it into the React Context. In this example I saved Keywords array of the first record of Documents but the end result is to save all the keywords records of all the documents records.

```
const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        localStorage.setItem("workview", JSON.stringify(json.Documents));
        localStorage.setItem(
          "keywords",
          JSON.stringify(json.Documents[0].Keywords)
        );
        dispatch(
          { type: "SET_WORKVIEW", payload: json.Documents },
          {
            type: "SET_KEYWORDS",
            payload: JSON.stringify(json.Documents[0].Keywords),
          }
        );
      }
```

Image of Local Storage:
[image: Local Storage Image]

The purpose of this is to use the Keywords array to create a table were the Keywords Name is the Column Name and the Keywords Value is the table data.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you dispatch as `keywords`:

```js
JSON.stringify(json.Documents[0].Keywords)
```

This is a `string` (`JSON.stringify`), not an `Array`.

You then try to iterate over `keywords`:

```js
keywords.map((keyword, index) => (...))
```

As `keywords` is a `string`, there's nothing to `map`.

If I had to bet, your solution would be to dispatch the array itself instead:

```js
  {
            type: "SET_KEYWORDS",
            payload: json.Documents[0].Keywords
  }
```